# Change text color inside offcanvas navbar

Tags: colors, off-canvas-menu

If I´m on a big screen, the text color on the navbar is white. However, when it gets smaller I have a offcanvas navbar with white background and I want the text color black.
Is it possible?

you can see the example code on bootstrap>Docs>navbar>Offcanvas

[.offcanvas-end .nav-link {color: black !important;}](https://stackoverflow.com)
did not work